# Android, setText and setTypeface don´t work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a small issue with something, which I have peformed many times and also correctly. I want use my **own font**, resp. external google Roboto Font for my text of buttons in MainActivity, so I use a simple code which works before, but not now in **onCreate()** method when application/activity starts. Then I try just chane text but it also don´t work. After app start, it stay like it is prescribed activity_main.xml, **anything change**. When I use a other button function for that, it works. Where is problem? Cause I want set it immediately after activity start.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DbHelper cryfi_db = new DbHelper(this);
    DbHelper_user user_db = new DbHelper_user(this);

    Button btn_ratings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ratings);
    Typeface roboto_light = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    btn_ratings.setTypeface(roboto_light);

    //here are some others working functions for sqlite dbs
}

public void onButtonClick(View v){
    Button btn_ratings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ratings);
    Typeface roboto_light = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    btn_ratings.setTypeface(roboto_light);
}
```

Can the problem be associated with functions for database or extending AppCompatActivity?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/iv_intro"
    android:src="@drawable/intro_1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_ratings"
    android:text="@string/ratings"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/intro_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_generate"
    android:text="@string/generate"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/intro_btn"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_ratings"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_ratings"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_ratings" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OtherButton"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ib_settings"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```

I have there others imageButtons, but they do not have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that your ttf file is inside the  main/assets/fonts folder.
And try the same code in

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus){
             Button btn_ratings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ratings);
             Typeface roboto_light = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
            btn_ratings.setTypeface(roboto_light);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am sure, it changed font with button click yet, but not in onCreate().

Comment: Thanks man, it works correct. Can you get me and also for others in for any quick explain why it have to be this way? Why that simple code dont´t work in onCreate() ?

Answer (score 0):

Use TypeFaceHelper class to cache the fonts and use them.

```
public class Typefaces{

    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, String name){
        synchronized(cache){
            if(!cache.containsKey(name)){
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s.ttf", name));
                cache.put(name, t);
            }
            return cache.get(name);
        }
    }    
}
```

Now you can use `Typefaces.get` to change your font.

```
btn_ratings.setTypeface(Typefaces.get(this, "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"));
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but it isn´t working. I call in onCreate() -
btn_ratings.setTypeface(Typefaces.get(this, "Roboto-Light"));
...but it stil stay as it is and font doesn´t change

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom button that will solve your issue :

```
public final class RobotoButton extends Button {
    private static Typeface mTypeface;
     public RobotoButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
         setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"));
     }
}
```

And in your xml :

```
<com.x.RobotoButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OtherButton"......./>
```